# Removing the Settings and Search shortcut from the start menu applications list

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

I want to remove all the default Windows 10 applications from the start menu list, and I have managed every single one except for the Settings shortcut and the search shortcut.

[image: This is what it looks like now]

Is it possible to remove those two last icons and start filling it up with my own custom shortcuts?

Comment: How did you go about removing built in system apps like Alarms & Clock and Calculator? What version of windows 10 are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 LTSB, all those default apps are removed by default. Everything that was there was just a shortcut in the start menu folder in the Windows directory. @mt025

Comment: I am in the process of writing an answer, but I have looked through multiple virtual machines all running different versions of windows 10 and none of them have a Search shortcut in the start menu.  Which makes me wonder, what it does, I assume it’s because your running an Enterprise 1607 (LTSB) and that’s the one version I have not checked.  So can you confirm it simply act like the search box that Windows 7 SP1 has?

Comment: @Ramhound: This doesn't exist either on Enterprise 1803, but Cortana and Search are both disabled.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove Settings from Windows 10 Start Menu**

- Launch Settings
- Click *Personalization*
- Click *Start* on the left
- Scroll down and click *Choose which folders appear on Start*
- Toggle the *Settings* option to Off

To can still access Settings by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

[image]

**Remove Search from Windows 10 Start Menu**

This is harder, since Search has become Cortana, and Microsoft loves Cortana.
I have not tried the manipulation described below, but they might also
break the general search in Windows 10. They are also not guaranteed
to work in the latest version.

I suggest before starting to create a system restore point, just in case,
since this might be destructive.
I wouldn't blame you if you skipped this section.

In elevated PowerShell session run the command:

```
remove-appxpackage Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.10.7.17134_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
```

If this does not work, to totally disable search, enter in an elevated
Command Prompt (cmd):

```
dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:SearchEngine-Client-Package
```

You might also be interested in the PowerShell script that does
[Remove Windows 10 Built-in Apps](http://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=10310),
which removes much Microsoft bloatware.

Another method for getting totally rid of Cortana is as follows:

- Go to `%WINDIR%\SystemApps`
- Take ownership of `Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy`
- Rename this folder. If successful then reboot, else continue.
- if Cortana is running, the dialog box *Folder Access Denied* will appear
- Click *Continue*.
- Leave the dialog box open, go to Task Manager, end the Cortana task, then very quickly click the *Try Again* button on the dialog box.
  Try again if not quick enough.
- Reboot.

For good measure, I add here the registry update for
disabling Web search in the Start Menu for Windows 10 version 1803 :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search]
"BingSearchEnabled"=dword:00000000
"AllowSearchToUseLocation"=dword:00000000
"CortanaConsent"=dword:00000000
```

If all this does not help, then this Search icon on the Start Menu might
come from a third-party product. You could verify by booting in Safe mode
and seeing if it's there.

Comment: Even after trying all three approaches still search option is present everywhere. I would appreciate if you could provide some solution through c# or it will be also ok if you could provide some source from Microsoft that it is not possible...

Comment: If you see Cortana running in the Task Manager, then I added above a method for final kill.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that it cannot be done, I have had the same issues preparing an image for thin clients. However as a work around you can use group policy and the GPO 'Software Restrictions' to stop people from using the search function.

Create new GPO Using path 'C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy'

Unfortunatley there is no GPO or Security settings you can use to remove these two icons. If you are using a thin client, you may also have write protection which will stop any setting changes any way, look under 'Control Panel'.