# Removing the Settings and Search icons from the start menu

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1809

I want to remove Search, Setting, Windows Security Icons from the start menu list in windows 10. I have managed to remove other icons.

Is anyone have an idea how to remove these icons?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?  You might be able to restrict access to Settings as you can restrict access to Control Panel but I doubt you can remove the icon or the application itself. In order to achieve this there is a good chance you will have to use something other than 1809 due to the link Cortana has with search in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the Settings and Search shortcut from the start menu applications list](https://superuser.com/questions/1320159/removing-the-settings-and-search-shortcut-from-the-start-menu-applications-list).  As I suggested remove Search might not be feasible with 1809, once `Windows 10 version 2004` is released, they have separated Search and Cortana and it will likely be a great deal easier to accomplish that task.